# grab multidimensional array on perl

Tags: arrays, perl, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to learn perl for parsing a file, but I got a problem here when parsing a multidimensional array.

```
>cat files
ge-1/1/1.81     up    up   NODEB_CLUSTER#81
ge-1/1/1.82     up    up   NODEB_CLUSTER#82
ge-1/1/1.2501   up    up   *** OM_nodeB_VLAN_2501 ***
ge-1/1/1.2502   up    up   *** OM_nodeB_VLAN_2502 ***
```

if I tried to push it with split spaces, it makes 4 column for first and second row, but 6 column for third and fourth row.

how do we split it and create an output like this:

```
ge-1/1/1.81,up,up,NODEB_CLUSTER#81
ge-1/1/1.82,up,up,NODEB_CLUSTER#82
ge-1/1/1.2501,up,up,*** OM_nodeB_VLAN_2501 ***
ge-1/1/1.2502,up,up,*** OM_nodeB_VLAN_2502 ***
```

thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use warnings;
use strict;

my @array  = <DATA>;
chomp (@array);
foreach (@array)
{
    my @a = split (/\s\s+/,$_);
    foreach (@a)
    {
        print "$_,";
    }
    print "\n";
}

__DATA__
ge-1/1/1.81     up    up   NODEB_CLUSTER#81
ge-1/1/1.82     up    up   NODEB_CLUSTER#82
ge-1/1/1.2501   up    up   *** OM_nodeB_VLAN_2501 ***
ge-1/1/1.2502   up    up   *** OM_nodeB_VLAN_2502 ***
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
ge-1/1/1.81,up,up,NODEB_CLUSTER#81,
ge-1/1/1.82,up,up,NODEB_CLUSTER#82,
ge-1/1/1.2501,up,up,*** OM_nodeB_VLAN_2501 ***,
ge-1/1/1.2502,up,up,*** OM_nodeB_VLAN_2502 ***,
```

Pay attention how I am splitting. You need `\s\s+` as there is space between `***` and `OM`.

The split will split on `2 spaces or more`. So this way, it will not split `*** OM...`
as there is only 1 space in between.

Comment: Or you could `split(/\s+/, $_, 4)` to stop splitting after four values.

Comment: TMTOWTDI. that's the beauty of perl.

Comment: s+ is for 2 spaces or more?

Comment: no. `\s+` if for one or more spaces. Hence I had to add `\s` before `\s+` so it means split on `2 or more` spaces.

Answer (score 0):

<del>Chomping the array isn't really doing anything good</del>

You can also explicitly match 2 or more spaces:

```
use warnings;                                                                                                                                                                                           
use strict;                                                                                                                                                                                             

foreach my $line (<DATA>)                                                                                                                                                                               
{                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    chomp($line); #remove newline                                                                                                                                                                       
    print join( ',',                                                                                                                                                                                    
            split( /\s{2,}/, $line ) #at least 2 spaces                                                                                                                                                 
        ), "\n";                                                                                                                                                                                        
}                                                                                                                                                                                                       

__DATA__                                                                                                                                                                                                
ge-1/1/1.81     up    up   NODEB_CLUSTER#81                                                                                                                                                             
ge-1/1/1.82     up    up   NODEB_CLUSTER#82                                                                                                                                                             
ge-1/1/1.2501   up    up   *** OM_nodeB_VLAN_2501 ***                                                                                                                                                   
ge-1/1/1.2502   up    up   *** OM_nodeB_VLAN_2502 ***
```

Comment: It does. Run my code by commenting out the `chomp` statement. you will see the difference. What is the BEST way to chomp is beyond the scope of this discussion.

Comment: Whoops, had no idea: [If you chomp a list, each element is chomped, and the total number of characters removed is returned.](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html)